# Is there any attribute or option available in weblogic to restrict number of servlets?

Tags: java

I'm working on java project, which is using weblogic 10 as an application server. In this project there are around 11 servlets added in web.xml descriptor with url mapping. Whenever i'm adding new servlet, its not getting mapped to the url as wel as not getting invoked. What may be the problem. As, if I add the same logic in any of the existing servlet, its working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps your changed `web.xml` is not getting deployed properly!

Comment: I checked that too..its getting deployed properly...but still not getting why weblogic is not reading that one...

Comment: How do you know that? AppServers usually keep an internal copy of deployment descriptors. What you see in the exploded war file may not always be used by the container. Try removing a few existing servlet declarations and see if yours takes effect.

Answer (score 0):

How is the question in the title of your post going to help you solve this problem?

Maybe you have another servlet that maps to the same URL pattern, or you have ambiguous URL patterns for your new servlet and already existing servlets (so that WebLogic doesn't know which one to call). Check the servlet mappings in your `web.xml` file.

Check the WebLogic management console to see if your servlet is deployed successfully, and check the logs of WebLogic for any deployment errors. Carefully read the error messages to find out what's wrong. If you don't understand them, add them to your post above, so that someone here can explain you what they mean.

If you go to an URL that's supposed to map to your servlet, then what do you get? An error message, or is it going to another servlet? If it's an error, then again, post the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I have checked there is no other servlet having same servlet name or same url mapping... there are no errors too...but when I'm requesting that servlet I'm getting 404 error... So, i will check the WebLogic management console to see if that servlet is deployed successfully...

Comment: 404 means that either the URL that you entered does not match the pattern that the servlet is mapped to, or the servlet wasn't deployed successfully.